# Delete cells with specific text on a range

Tags: vba, excel

I have a range up that's 5k or so cells and I want to remove the cells that has specific texts on it. I.E. And, a, is, that, or, with, the, etc. Is there a way to this? Please help.

```
[A2].Select
Range("A2", Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

Dim crnge As Range
Dim wdelim
Dim rdelim

wdelim = Split("on,the,this,in,at,of,for,what,w,all,on,with", ",")

Set crnge = Selection

For Each rdelim In wdelim
    crnge.wdelim.Select
    .Delete (xlUp)
Next
```

I know this code doesn't work, this is just what I'm trying to do but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Delete the cells or just clear their content?

Comment: Delete the cells and shift up. I'm actually thinking of the `Split` option and just loop it with a `For` statement but I'm not really sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I filter the data for each element in the array and delete all the entire row of visible cells.

```
Sub DeleteFilteredRows()
    Dim v
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    For Each v In Split("on,the,this,in,at,of,for,what,w,all,on,with", ",")
        With Range("A1").CurrentRegion
            On Error Resume Next
            'If you want all rows that have any of this phrases anywhere in
            'the cell use: Criteria1:="=*" & v & "*"                             

            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=" & v , Operator:=xlAnd
            .Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
            On Error GoTo 0
            .AutoFilter

        End With

    Next

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tested it ? I tested it with my data , and when one of the elements inside the `Split` is missing (i.e I don't have anything with "this"), it returned an error.

Comment: I tested it but can you double check? [Download DeleteFilteredRows.xlsm](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a2xu8wrolkkfmt5/DeleteFilteredRows.xlsm?dl=0)

Comment: In your file you have all of the cases, remove all the "this" or "in" and you are getting an error (the `On Error Resume Next` is not trapping this)

Comment: Never mind, I see it was marked as answer, so the PO is happy

Comment: @ShaiRado Thanks for double checking.  I'm not getting any unhandled errors. [Image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c36tppplezvaf0r/DeleteFilteredRows.gif?dl=0)

Comment: It works but it's actually removing other words as well. Like There is removed since it has The on it. Is there a way to make work as the verbatim itself?

Comment: I updated my answer.  I was using wildcards to remove any occurrence of the words. (e.g. "w" would remove "w","work","where","how are you", ...etc.)

Comment: You're a life saver. Thanks a lot!